# Can a C compiler omit a cast to a type having the same underlying type as the source type?

Tags: c, casting

Recently I got accross the following piece of code in C:

```
typedef enum { AAA, BBB } enumtype;
enumtype var;
void func(uint8_t* par);

..

func(&(uint8_t)var);
```

To me this is a nonsense as we are passing an address of a temporary variable (the result of a cast) to the function as a parameter. However, to my surprise, the compiler did not complain. What is important, an enum was stored as one byte according to compilation options, so no real action was hidden behind the cast. When I changed uint8_t to uint16_t as below, the compiler - as expected - raised an error due to an adress of a non-l-value was taken.

```
typedef enum { AAA, BBB } enumtype;
enumtype var;
void func(uint16_t* par);

..

func(&(uint16_t)var);
```

Now the question: is the compiler allowed (according to C standard) to skip the casting if the underlying types of the variable and the underlying type of the type it's being casted to are the same?

Comment: What does it mean to not "skip" casting a value to the type it already is?  What is it that isn't being done?

Comment: Assuming you ran this with `gcc`, did you have `-Wpedantic` enabled?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint..https://ideone.com/tQ70pm  Even if you choose the very same type: https://ideone.com/Y99IZu

Comment: There are not much "actions" to be taken when casting integral types. mostly none at all.

Comment: The compiler should have thrown an error on this code.  If it didn't, turn up your warning level.

Comment: What does it mean, casting to a type that it already is? What is there for the compiler to do?

Comment: @2501 I'm not disappointed - an error is what I expect. I wonder if a compiler not throwing an error is in accordance to the standard.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't something like `func(&(uint8_t){var})`, which uses a compound literal?

Comment: @Cormac O'Brien It's not gcc, it's Green Hills compiler.

Comment: You should show how, with what, and where are you compiling.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, it was exactly the case I have put in the question, no compound literal. The program was compiled in C89 mode. And as stated, after changing uint8_t to uint16_t the expected error occurred. My assumption is that the compiler removed the cast when it saw the types are the same. This way it removed an element which made the statement syntax incorrect. I'm wonderring if the compiler is allowed to do it or was it an error in the compiler.

Comment: @mrn Please put the name of the compiler and how you called it in the question itself.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.4 Cast operators 5 Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the
expression to the named type. This construction is called a cast. 104) A cast does not yield an lvalue.[...] 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators 1 The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
[] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
not declared with the register storage-class specifier.* This is a constraint violation, the compiler must complain.

Comment: @EOF You should post that as an answer.